# Google UA not connecting event to previous sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am sending an offline event to Google UA using their measurement protocol. I am trying to tie it to the users previous visits to get attribution and using Google's own Client ID from their cookie to do that. While the event does appear in Google UA, it is not tied to other client id sessions.

[Here an example of the API call](https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-Y&v=1&ec=phone&ea=Inbound%20Call&ev=2&el=AMC1&cid=1859919454.1455744839)

In this example, "1859919454.1455744839" are the X.Y elements parsed from the _ga cookie's client id.

Am I doing something wrong or making some wrong assumptions about google analytics accepting their own Client ID instead of creating and using my own as suggested in their measurement protocol's parameter reference? I have seen plenty of forum threads that suggest google's own client id is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your API call and you are missing a measurement protocol parameter in the URL "t" (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#t)
which defines what type of hit you are trying to send i.e. event or pageView

Google has created a debug tool to check whether the url generated is valid or not. You can also send hits to your GA using the tool.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

Answer (score 0):

turns out there is an unpublished parameter in the newer UA interface that allows for strict or loose userid. If strictly enforced, the userid MUST be a UUID. If strict is false it will accept google's own user id. Once that parameter is passed everything worked